# Parse.com how to enable client pushes

Tags: parse-platform

I'm targeting specific users when sending Parse notifications, using their email address.  The send seems to work okay, but no message is received. What do I need to change to receive the message? 
In my Parse control panel it shows the attempted pushes but with the error message that "client-initiated pushes are not enabled".  I really prefer initiating the pushes from the client.  How do I enable that?  I keep finding documentation that says to enable client pushes but I can't find how to do it.

Here is my setup:

```
        Parse.initialize(this, "...xxxAPP_ID", "...xxxCLIENT_KEY");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(); 
        ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("defaultObject");
        parseObject.put("email", sEmail)
        parseObject.saveInBackground();
```

The actually sending is done here:

```
    ParseQuery pQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery(); 
    pQuery.whereEqualTo("email", ToUser); 
    ParsePush parsePush = new ParsePush();
    parsePush.setQuery(pQuery);
    parsePush.sendMessageInBackground("You have pictures waiting from " + sEmail, pQuery);

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" 
    android:name="com.pictureplay.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.pictureplay.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.pictureplay" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Update: I have narrowed the problem down to push notifications being received unless the service is not running.  I thought the Parse service was supposed to load when the phone restarts, but this is not the case here.  Is there a way to get the Parse service for my app to load when the phone reboots?

Update2:
The solution was to create a separate class (called "App" in my case) which initializes Parse.  If the Parse service gets shut down when the app closes, the service restarts itself within minutes (automatically, I did no special setup for this) to be able to receive incoming push messages. These are the lines of code used in "App" onCreate:

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "data1", "data2");  //supply your own 
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

Comment: it's a setting you disabled in the Settings dashboard on Parse.com

Comment: Great, thanks.  I sure couldn't find that simple step in the setup tutorial. BTW, I didn't disable it... it was that way by default since this is the first time I accessed it. Now client push is working but notifications are still not being received.  Any tips on that?

Comment: Some place to start:  https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#troubleshooting/Android

Comment: Looking through the troubleshooting steps, the only step I'm not sure about is "Check that the device is set to accept push notifications from your app."  How is this step done.?  In my code above I have a default activity setup.  Is there more to it?

Comment: Yes: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Comment: I already had those setup details.  I must be missing something else.  Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 6):

Have you enable Sending notifications from Client. Its a setting in Parse.com. 
Go to settings ->App Permissions ->Allow client class creation. Set it to ON>

Comment: Yes, Fosco showed me that too.  That was part of what I needed.

Comment: @user2431174 I have enabled that option ,, still not working same exception com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Client-initiated push isn't enabled. is coaming please help me if possible

Answer (score 1):

In your parse application Go to settings > Push > Client Push Enabled > set to Yes

Answer (score 0):

The question *Is there a way to get the Parse service for my app to load when the phone reboots?* : Yes you can receive the `BOOT_COMPLETE` event if you have added the following permission on your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I have the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in Manifest file but the service still doesn't start when the phone boots.  The push isn't received until the app it started once... that is until the service gets loaded.  What am I missing to get the service loaded at boottime?

Comment: @user2431174 You are not missing anything. Note that as of Android 3.0 the user needs to have started the application at least once before your application can receive android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED events.

Comment: Thanks Subin.  It looks like I'm doing all I can to send push notifications then. Somewhat disappointing as it is now a "chicken and egg" problem: the user doesn't know he has data waiting so he doesn't start the app, but he doesn't start the app because he doesn't know he has data waiting.  Only frequent users will get timely pushes. Maybe I should use optional text messages in preferences as backup.

Answer (score 0):

In the new Parse DashBoard: go to settings---> push ---> push notification settings---> client enabled push --- >set to "yes"